# Make synchronous connection without effecting the ui ios

Tags: ios7

I need to implement the scenerio like I have to make synchronous calls (no count on service calls) to web service when app is in foreground, but the calls should not effect the UI. Need idea on the same.
Do we have any problems if we make this kind of scenerio. please advice me if any

Answer (score 1):

In order to not affect the UI, the calls can't be made from the main thread (else it would have to wait for such calls to finish); thus, if they're on another thread, you'd be OK, at least given the sketchy details you've provided.